# git - how can I configure interactive commits to always show a diff?

Tags: git, commit, git-diff

I want `git commit` to always do a `git commit -v` without typing the `-v`

I can't see to be able to make a bash alias as it is two words with a space :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a function to `~/.bash_profile` or similar

```c
git () {
  if [[ $1 = commit ]]
  then
    command git commit -v "${@:2}"
  else
    command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to type in a slightly different command
(git won't let you alias git built-in commands), set up a
git alias

```c
git config --global alias.ci 'commit -v'
```

The drawback is you have to then `git ci` instead of
`git commit`. Might be just as easy to remember the `-v`.